# Why does someone in our apartment complex yell something like "dòuhé" at around 8am?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word, accent

Basically every morning at around 8am, there's someone outside my apartment in Beijing yelling something that sounds like dòuhé, which is audible in everyone's apartment.

I managed to record him saying it: [here](https://soundcloud.com/rebecca-stones/douhe).

I have no idea what this means (I can't find it [in Pleco](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPnLJ.jpg)).  He might be selling something (like breakfast), or it might be related to garbage collection.

**Question**: Why does someone in our apartment complex yell something like "dòuhé" at around 8am?

---

Okay, I went down to his van this morning and took a photo of what's inside:

> [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if i heard right, he was yelling 豆腐。I think he was selling tofu. Some Chinese northerners especially when shouting for selling 豆腐，the pronunciation is sometimes changed from "doufu" to "doufe".

edited:
yes you see, it's tofu. I think this website can help you:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tofu

the weird pronunciation is, as I said before, just because of the northern accent. I think the reason may be "doufe" is easier to be loud than "doufu". They must make sure more people can hear he is selling something

Answer (score 3):

After listening to the recording, It sounds more like 早飯 (breakfast) /Zǎofàn/

To confirm my theory, please go out at 8:00 AM and find the street vendor around your apartment and see what he's selling

*It doesn't sound like [豆汁](https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/zh/%E8%B1%86%E6%B1%81) /Dòuzhī/ Douzhi as I previously thought, although 豆汁 which is a breakfast food unique to Beijing City does make very good sense*

It also sounds like [豆花](https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/zh/%E8%B1%86%E8%8A%B1) (Douhua) but 豆花 is called 豆腐腦 in the north